# Won't recognize user input in Python 3

Tags: python, input

So, I'm writing a program that gives the person a random name and then asks the user if they like that name and, if not, it will give them a new one.

```
new_name = str(input("If you are not happy with your name, type 'New name please', if you're good, type I'm good.")).upper 
if new_name in ["NEW NAME PLEASE", "NEW NAME PLEASE.", "NEW NAME PLZ"]:
  print("Ok, you're Hugh Janus! Try not to say that out loud.")
else:
  print("Lovely! Let's carry on!")
```

The program won't recognize when I type in "new name please". I even tried typing in all caps to see if it was a problem with .upper but nothing happened.

Comment: You need to _call_ `upper`. Add parentheses at the end.

Comment: `.upper` is not `.upper()`; BTW `input()` returns a string in Python 3, so no need to cast it

Comment: You do too much in a single line of code (the first line). You should split it up in order to help you see what the problem is.

Comment: `str` is unnecessary since `input()` returns a string.

Comment: For future reference, you should provide a complete transcript of running your program. It is especially important to include an error  with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `str` from line 1 since `input` returns `string`. On line one also change `upper` to `upper()` That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with the string "NEW NAME PLEASE", you must have parenthesis at the end of upper() as it is a method.